# Create constraints programmatically didn't work well

Tags: ios, swift

I created a button with constraints programmatically. But the button moved to a wrong position (bottom right). What did I wrong?

```
    item = UIButton(type: .custom)
    item.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    item.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayController.itemAct(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    item.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(item)

    // Constraints
    item.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    item.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 441).isActive = true
    item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 123).isActive = true
    item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 222).isActive = true
    item.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 196).isActive = true
```

**Edit:**

If you want to create left, right, top, bottom you should set minus values to `item.trailingAnchor` and `item.bottomAnchor`, works for me.

Comment: You're over constraining it, for one.  It is enough to set top and leading constraints after you have set width and height.  Don't constrain it from both left and right and don't constrain it from both top and bottom when you've set width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of some of my code via constraints, as there are many different ways. Here is one of my more favorite ways:

```
containerView.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        ])
```

Make sure you add the constraints to the container view

Also note that if you do it like yours, you only wanna add the top/left/right/bottom or top/left/width/height. You only ever need 4 at most (usually)